# Problems with Meteor deployment related to fibers module

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

While trying to deploy meteor, I install node fiber by:

```
$ cd bundle/server
```

and then installing fiber

```
$ npm install fibers
```

It seems to install but with this message:

```
`linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers
```

However, while deploying the code using:

```
node bundle/main.js
```

I get this error:

```
throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibe
~/main_repo/bundle/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.20/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?
```

I can see that the versions are different for linux-x64-v8-3.xx. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04

Node version is v0.11.3
NPM version is 1.2.18

Comment: Why are you doing this? Just use `meteor bundle mydeploy.zip` to bundle it.

Comment: try `npm install -g fibers`

Comment: Those steps are after using meteor bundle. I use the install/uninstall fibers because that's how I've been deploying on my other servers.npm -g install fibers also gives me the same error.

Comment: First of all, Meteor is not meant to run on Node 0.11 yet. 0.8.18 is officially supported node version. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I used nvm to downgrade to v0.8.18 for node and 1.2.2 for npm. However, it still gives me the same issue. The new message is `linux-x64-v8-3.11` exists; testing. Note previously, it said 3.14. However, while deploying it still gives me "Try reinstalling `node-fibers" looking for "linux-x64-v8-3.20/fibers.node". Why is it looking for this file. I tried changing the code so it looks for 3.14 instead. Hardcoding didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall fibers first to remove the binary that's not compatible with your server's platform.

```
cd bundle/server
npm uninstall fibers 
npm install fibers
```

You only need to do this if your server is using a different platform, i.e if your development pc is not ubuntu.

Comment: We develop on osX. We deploy on CentOS. In that case we're using the uninstall/install fibers method and it works perfectly. However, owing to some issues with apache running on the same server, a lot of solutions like reverse proxy and binding to another IP don't seem to be working perfectly. Hence, we moved the deployment to another machine running Ubuntu 13.04. And that's how we're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There are some version issues.
It's worked for me:

```
cd bundle/server
npm uninstall fibers
npm install fibers@1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
sudo npm install -g nvm

npm WARN deprecated nvm@0.0.3: This is NOT the correct nvm. Visit http://nvm.sh and use the curl command to install it.
```

Then I put nvm on with this:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash
```

npm gave a warning like this:

```
=> You currently have modules installed globally with `npm`. These will no
=> longer be linked to the active version of Node when you install a new node
=> with `nvm`; and they may (depending on how you construct your `$PATH`)
=> override the binaries of modules installed with `nvm`:

/usr/local/lib
├── bitcoinjs-lib@2.1.4
├── bower@1.6.5
├── cordova@5.4.1
├── ember-cli@1.13.8
├── fibers@1.0.8
├── grunt-cli@0.1.13
├── gulp@3.9.0
├── ionic@1.7.12
├── ios-deploy@1.8.2
├── ios-sim@5.0.3
├── lite-server@1.3.2
└── nvm@0.0.3

=> If you wish to uninstall them at a later point (or re-install them under your
=> `nvm` Nodes), you can remove them from the system Node as follows:

     $ nvm use system
     $ npm uninstall -g a_module
```

So I did `nvm use system`.
Now using system version of node: v4.2.4 (npm v2.14.12)

went and uninstalled everything:

```
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g bower
unbuild bower@1.6.5
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g cordova
unbuild cordova@5.4.1
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g ember-cli
unbuild ember-cli@1.13.8
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g fibers
unbuild fibers@1.0.8
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g grunt-cli
unbuild grunt-cli@0.1.13
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g gulp
unbuild gulp@3.9.0
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g ionic
unbuild ionic@1.7.12
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g ios-deploy
unbuild ios-deploy@1.8.2
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g ios-sim
unbuild ios-sim@5.0.3
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g lite-server
unbuild lite-server@1.3.2
sh-3.2# npm uninstall -g nvm
unbuild nvm@0.0.3
sh-3.2#

Downgraded to node 0.10.36:

nvm install 0.10.36
```

Now maybe I can run it. So I delete the whole app folder and re-create with this:

```
hotel:Sites tom$ meteor create --example localmarket
Created a new Meteor app in 'localmarket'.
```

To run your new app:

```
cd localmarket
meteor
```

If you are new to Meteor, try some of the learning resources here: https://www.meteor.com/learn

```
hotel:Sites tom$ cd localmarket/
hotel:localmarket tom$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/Dropbox/Sites/localmarket ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
W20160118-22:04:11.145(13)? (STDERR)
W20160118-22:04:11.146(13)? (STDERR) module.js:340
W20160118-22:04:11.147(13)? (STDERR)     throw err;
W20160118-22:04:11.148(13)? (STDERR)           ^
W20160118-22:04:11.148(13)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
W20160118-22:04:11.148(13)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
W20160118-22:04:11.148(13)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
W20160118-22:04:11.148(13)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W20160118-22:04:11.149(13)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
W20160118-22:04:11.149(13)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tom/Dropbox/Sites/localmarket/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
W20160118-22:04:11.149(13)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
W20160118-22:04:11.149(13)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
W20160118-22:04:11.149(13)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
W20160118-22:04:11.149(13)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
W20160118-22:04:11.150(13)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160118-22:04:21.515(13)? (STDERR)
W20160118-22:04:21.516(13)? (STDERR) module.js:340
W20160118-22:04:21.516(13)? (STDERR)     throw err;
W20160118-22:04:21.516(13)? (STDERR)           ^
W20160118-22:04:21.516(13)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
W20160118-22:04:21.516(13)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
W20160118-22:04:21.517(13)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
W20160118-22:04:21.517(13)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W20160118-22:04:21.517(13)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
W20160118-22:04:21.517(13)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tom/Dropbox/Sites/localmarket/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
W20160118-22:04:21.517(13)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
W20160118-22:04:21.519(13)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
W20160118-22:04:21.519(13)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
W20160118-22:04:21.519(13)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
W20160118-22:04:21.519(13)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

ah dang ok that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Node version is v0.11.3 NPM version is 1.2.18

Meteor 1.3.3 and before only uses up to Node v0.10.4x.

Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to run specific node versions.

**References**

- [Upgrading Node.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5124)
- [Meteor + NodeJS 0.12](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-nodejs-0-12/2769)